# Angular - src(unknown) image

Tags: html, angular

```js
retrieveProjects() {
    this.afs
      .collection(Project.collectionName)
      .get()
      .subscribe((resp) => {
        if (resp == null || undefined) {
          this.noProjects = true;
          return;
        }
        resp.forEach((project) => {
          const data = project.data() as Project;
          if (
            data.projectImageDownloadURL === undefined ||
            data.projectImageDownloadURL === null ||
            data.projectImageDownloadURL === ''
          ) {
            data.projectImageDownloadURL = 'assets/images/Project_Default.svg';
          }
          this.projects.push(data);
        });
      });
  }
```

I'm trying to figure out why my img tag has src(unknown). I've looked at other articles and posts and I'm still confused as to why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[Inspect element on google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqoBY.png)

```html
 <img
          class="projimg center"
          [src]="hit.projectImageDownloadURL"
          (click)="navigate(hit.id)"
        />
```

Comment: Please post code. Anyway, do you get some errors in console?

Comment: I just posted some, apologies. - There are no errors in the console.

Comment: You can also show how your image url and ts file looks like.

Comment: @tmsbrndz Thank you, I apologize. I'm pretty new to this. Thank you, sorry let me know if I can add anything else. Apologies.

Comment: Maybe you should try another default image, eg. something from Google with full path.